# How can I prevent UINavigationItems from being pushed onto a UINavigationBar managed by a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I want to build a custom navigation bar that handles navigating back through the stack differently than the stock `UINavigationBar` does. In order to do this, a core requirement is that the navigation bar never change its set of `UINavigationItem` objects so that it always has one item with the same left and right bar items and the same custom view. The custom view is intended to have a breadcrumb-style view that will allow for users to go back 1 or many view controllers at a time.

I'm trying to accomplish this by using a plain `UINavigationController` that uses a custom `UINavigationBar` subclass like so:

```
window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[BreadcrumbNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
```

And in the bar class I just (for now) intercept all the calls that supposedly modify the `UINavigationItem`s in the nav bar and do nothing instead:

```
@implementation BreadcrumbNavigationBar

- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items
{
}

- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
{
}

- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated
{
}

- (UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

However this doesn't work. If I navigate to a new screen the navigation bar pushes a new item onto its stack when ostensibly it shouldn't. But the back button on the new item doesn't go back for some reason.

Is what I want to do possible? The alternative to using `UINavigationController` would be to use a custom navigation controller that mimicked the appearance and behavior of `UINavigationController` but behaved how I want regarding the nav bar; however there's a lot of nice behavior `UINavigationController` gives me for free that I don't want to have to re-implement if possible.

**Edit**

After posting this I found this post:

[UINavigationBar -pushNavigationItem never called when new controller is pushed onto UINavigationController stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356459/uinavigationbar-pushnavigationitem-never-called-when-new-controller-is-pushed-o)

if I also implement `- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item` then things kind of work for the first navigation item; however if I fill the methods out a bit to only ever keep one item in the items array, when I push a view controller onto the stack, the nav bar behaves as if the `UIBarButtonItem`s from the root view controller no longer appear, even though the item is prevented from being pushed with in the `pushNavigationItem` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a standard `UINavigationController` as a parent container. The rootViewController would be a `UINavigationController` subclass that hides its `UINavigationBar` and has the correct left and right navigation buttons in its navigation item.

```
    //You would need to populate these variables
    UIViewController * actualController;
    UIBarButtonItem * rightBarButtonItem;
    UIBarButtonItem * leftBarButtonItem;

    UINavigationController * childNavigator = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:actualController];
    [childNavigator setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [[childNavigator navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem];
    [[childNavigator navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButtonItem];

    UINavigationController * parentNavigator = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:childNavigator];
```

Your actual view controllers would push and pop on the child `UINavigationController` that has no `UINavigationBar`. The displayed `UINavigationBar` is never changed based on push/pop actions.

Comment: That's an option; the only sticky part would be changing the `edgesForExtendedLayout` on the inner navigation controller when a new controller was pushed or popped, and making sure that gets propagated upwards to the containing nav controller. I'm using a custom view controller that i believe works just the same without that presently; if a compelling reason to change to your suggested implementation comes up then i'll try it out.